# Jersey REST Service throws exception after Migration to Tomcat 9 : SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, rest, jersey

In the catalina logs :-
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.3
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:

**SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.update(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 0**

**SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.update(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 1**

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response update(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                       @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData,
                       @PathParam("id") String id) {

uploadFile(uploadedInputStream, fileMetaData, id);

return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build();

}
```

This error started after our Application migrated from using Apache Tomcat 7.0.100 to Apache Tomcat 9.0.24

Comment: Please show all your dependencies and your app configuration (web.xml or ResourceConfig or both)

Comment: Please let me know what you need to check as I cannot list the entire xml/config due to security reasons.

Comment: Anything relevant to Jersey I need to see